# Installing Xamarin Mac Agent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have vs2017 Enterprise installed on my Windows dev machine with all the Xamarin component but I'm not clear what I need to install on the mac to get 
the "Xamarin Mac Agent" running.

Following these instructions: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/#macintosh

[image]

It says I need to install Xamarin iOS SDK. Where can I find that install?

Comment: install VS Mac and it will include the SDKs

Comment: I'm just borrowing the mac, so I was hoping didn't need the bloat of Visual Studio. Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation#manual-installation Grab the manual installation guide and then you know how to only install the SDK.

Comment: I'm afraid you must install VS on MAC, check [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/#Installing_Xamarin.iOS)